# How to change categorical responses to quatitative in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, categories

I have a data table that column of male and female and one with yes and no responses, I just need to change these to 0 and 1 values, how do I go about that?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that you really do need to do this but here's how (assuming they are factors):

```
numMF <- as.numeric(MFfac) -1 # will be 0 for F and 1 for M in the usual sorting of factor levels
```

If they are really character vectors, then wrap factor around the MFfac that I assumed was a factor. Or:

```
numMF <- match(MFvec, c("Female", "Male") ) -1

 match( c("Female","Male", "Female"),  c("Female", "Male") )
[1] 1 2 1
```

The match function is an important resource for data conversions.

Comment: right about `match`; also, when there are only two possible values like here, a simple `==`: `ifelse(df$Sex == "Male", 1, 0)` or `as.numeric(df$Sex == "Male")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce a factor directly to a numeric vector: `as.numeric(factor(x))`. If the default level ordering is not to your liking, specify the levels explicitly with the "levels" argument to "factor".

Answer (score 0):

The general way to convert factors to indicator variables is using the `model.matrix` function.  But most of the time you don't need to do this because the modeling functions (such as `lm`) will call `model.matrix` for you.